# Can we invoke one module's leaf device direct method from another module?

Tags: .net, azure, iot, azure-iot-edge

I have developed two custom IoT edge modules
e.g. **Module1, Module2**

Module1 is having multiple IoT devices (Leaf devices) running inside the container.

Those leaf devices have certain direct methods written e.g. **IsDeviceOnline**

Is it possible to invoke that direct method from **Module2**?

I have tried by writing leaf deviceId while invoking as below but it gives
`{"status":500,"payload":null}`
always.

```
MethodRequest request = new MethodRequest("IsDeviceOnline");
var resp = await moduleclient.InvokeMethodAsync(deviceId, "Module1", request);
```

above code is getting executed from Module2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution...

I have just removed moduleId and it is working fine

```
MethodRequest request = new MethodRequest("IsDeviceOnline");
         // Execute request
         var resp = await moduleclient.InvokeMethodAsync(deviceId, request);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved. Please accept your solution as an answer so that it helps others as well.

Comment: Adding the same question asked in Q&A for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/72328/index.html

Comment: Sure, Accepted it